# Is it possible to create a numpy array from data pointing to same object in memory

Tags: python, numpy

suppose we have two scalars with type of numpy.float32:

```
a
 >>>1.0
type(a)
 >>><class 'numpy.float32'>
b
 >>>2.0
type(b)
 >>><class 'numpy.float32'>
```

I am trying to create a numpy array from list([a,b,a,a,b,b,b,a,b,b,a,a,a,b,b,a,a]).

My question is, can we make this array point its scalars to same object in memory? instead of copying them per stride of its shape?

I have a very long array e.g shape(1,30000), which consist of a few scalars (around 30) sequenced in different orders e.g 1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,2,2,3,1,2,1,1,3...

Creating this array take a huge amount of memory, but since they are actualy same scalars repeated, I thought there might be a way to load them once in memory and point array members to them.

Comment: Concerning memory, the "original copying" way would actually use less memory, 32bit per item. The "pointer" approach would store a pointer to a number per item, usually today 64bit per item

Comment: Arrays of pointers (object dtype) take just as much memory (if not more) than numeric dtypes, and generally are slower to work with.  Often a list (which also uses pointers) are faster.  The fast efficient compiled numpy code is written for numeric dtypes.

Comment: @hpaulj yes that is correct. even creating an empty array with defined shape and dtype will occupy same amount of memory. that is how numpy works. might try to use lists instead as you said.

Answer (score 0):

One way that might help you reduce half memory if your array size is smaller than 32767 (which is maximum int16 in numpy, try: `np.iinfo(np.int16).max`) is to store array of indices of your values as int16 instead of array of values itself, with a cost of calling the value from another list. Although this will be almost useless in a sense that you cannot leverage array calculations without making the array of values:

```
values = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=np.float32)
indices = np.array([1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,2,2,3,1,2,1,1,3], dtype=np.int16)
```

Comment: well, there are time where I have floats. it is not always integers.

Comment: @kevaes indices are always integers (if they are numbers). Do not mistake indices for values. They are different